# not show data in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i write this code for show album of singer by id . it find album of singer but it not append in dropdown list  . what's the problem ?

```
<script>
    function GetAlbum() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Music/GetAlbum',
            data: { ID: $("#SingerId").val() },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "josn",
            success: function (mata) {
                $("#AlbumId option").remove();
                $.each(mata,
                    function (index, element) {
                        var option = $('<option value="' +
                            element.ID +
                            '">' +
                            element.AlbumName +
                            '</option>');
                        $("#AlbumId").append(option);
                    });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetAlbum();
    });
    jQuery("#SingerID").change(function () {
        GetAlbum();
    });
</script>
```

[image]

```
  <select name="AlbumId" class="form-control" id="AlbumId"></select>
```

Comment: do you be using the razor?

Comment: Razor ? No ....